# Workaround for classList `undefined` in legacy browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works in all modern browser but on legacy it throws an error. How can I work around this?

Error:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById("profile").classList' [undefined] is not an object.
```

Code:

```
document.getElementById("mixdesign").addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd",    design);

function design(){
  "use strict";
  document.getElementById("profile").classList.add("animation");
  location.href = "#profile"; 
}
```

see Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mm0o5jhw/3/

Comment: It dosen't make much difference, I will add the jquery but is it an error simply due to compatibility on older browsers? Just curious???

Comment: `classList` isn't supported by IE9 and older. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist).

Answer (score 3):

[IE9 and older don't support `classList`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist). As you've tagged the question with jQuery, you can use `$.fn.addClass` instead:

`$("#profile").addClass("animation")`.

Answer (score 1):

As `classList` is not supported on older browsers you'll either need a polyfill, or use jQuery's `addClass` method on the element, or just use plain old vanillaJS:

```
document.getElementById("profile").className += " animation";
```

Answer (score 1):

> Using classList is a convenient alternative to accessing an element's list of classes as a space-delimited string via element.className.

It exits only in IE10 and up

```
String.prototype.trim = String.prototype.trim || function () {
   return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
};

 function getClassList(elem) {
     var trimmedClasses = elem.getAttribute("class").trim();

      return trimmedClasses ? trimmedClasses.split(/\s+/) : [];
 }

 function addClass(elem, c) {
     var classes = getClassList(elem);

     classes.push(c);

     elem.className = classes.join(" ");
 }
```

this is a naive implementation you can use the more robust solution in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 1):

The **[Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** Api starts from IE10.

For a cross-browser support you have to use **[Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/className)**.

The difference is that classList is an array and has *add* and *remove* methods, className is a simple string...

You've tagged the question with jQuery, jQuery is perfect for these tasks!

```js
function addClass() {
  var newClass = document.getElementById('baz').value || 'not-filled';
  
  var classes = document.getElementById('foo').className.split(' ');
  
  classes.push(newClass)
  
  return document.getElementById('foo').className = classes.join(' ');
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" class="class1 class2 class3 classN"></div>

<div style="padding: 1em;">
  <input type="text" id="baz" />
  <button onclick="addClass()">Add Class</button>
</div>
```